# Attribute between in filter_expression does not work when mocking DynamoDB using moto

Tags: boto3, dynamodb-queries, moto

My test setup looks like the following:

```
    @mock_dynamodb2
    def test_name(self, dynamodb_connection):
        create_table(dynamodb_connection)
        table = dynamodb_connection.Table(os.environ["table"])
        table.put_item(Item=create_item())
        items = get_items()
```

The following record is stored:

[image: Scan result]

When invoking the following query locally, in a mocked environment, the result is returned:

```
get_table("table").query(
    IndexName="org-index",
    KeyConditionExpression=Key("org").eq(org),
    FilterExpression=Attr("status").gte(0) & Attr("status").lte(10)
```

The same code in AWS production will return 0 results. Changing the query to use the `between` attribute instead (`Attr("status").between(0, 10)`) works on DynamoDB in the cloud, but **does not** work locally. I'd hate to merge test with prod code by doing a check. Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: Can you post the table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug with `between(0, 10)` where the 0 was treated as a no-value.
This has been fixed just now, as of moto >= 2.2.14.dev25.